# Split keyboard, switches with small travel distance, swappable keys

Tags: keyboards

## Requirements

- Split: 2 separate halves, the connecting wire must be long enough to have the 2 halves on either side when I'm sitting and typing on the floor.
- Shallow & quiet keystrokes: I prefer minimal noise and the short travel distance of laptop keyboard switches. I mostly use small and quick movements, mostly moving just my fingers with minimal wrist movement.
- Backlight: just single colored LEDs backlight (red or white)
- Swappable keys: I use vim and things with vim functions so I currently have CAPS & ESC swapped in my `.xinitrc` but even that doesn't always work so I wanna be able to swap them at the hardware level
- Wired: don't wanna go wireless for this

## Budget

50-100 USD is an easy yes, can save for up to around 500 USD.

(I'm currently in South East Asia so it must be deliverable there)